# How to know the Proxy is working in curl/php

Tags: php, curl, proxy

How to know that the proxy is working or not in curlphp

```
            $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 0);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXYPORT,8080);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXYTYPE, 'HTTP');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXY,'218.213.90.92');
        $head = curl_exec($ch);
        curl_close($ch);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set your `$url` to `"https://soulogic.com/ip/"`

If return `::ffff:218.213.90.92`, it means proxy is working.

Or on your server side, make a PHP file wroten:

```
<?php
echo $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"];
```